# Logging to Elastic search is not working while pointing to docker url in Api docker image

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, .net-core, docker-compose

Logging to Elastic search work fine when testing from local debugging to localhost app connection to elasticsearch url at https://localhost:9200, but it fails to connect with docker images of the **dotnet.monitoring.api** to the docker image of Elastic search at http://elasticsearch:9200
Below is the docker compose file.

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  productdb:
    container_name: productdb
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "SwN12345678"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"

  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - node.name=elasticsearch
      - cluster.name-es-docker-cluster
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
    networks:
      - es-net
    volumes:
      - data01:/urs/share/elasticsearch/data 
    ports:
      - 9200:9200

  kibana:
    container_name: kibana
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200
    networks:
      - es-net
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
  
  dotnet.monitoring.api:
    container_name: dotnet.monitoring.api
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - "ElasticConfiguration:Url=http://elasticsearch:9200/"
      - "ConnectionStrings:Product=server=productdb;Database=ProductDb;User Id=sa;Password=SampleP@&&W0rd;TrustServerCertificate=True;"
    depends_on:
      - productdb
      - kibana
    ports:
      - "8001:80"
volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local
networks:
  es-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: dotnet.monitoring.api is .Net 6 WebApi

Answer (score 1):

Your image of API is not in the same network. Make es-net as default.

```
networks:
  default:
    name: es-net
    external: true
```